# What do you call an oozing light you see from a distance in the landscape?

Tags: word-request

[image: light]

I can't think of a specific term or even a phrase to describe it correctly. I would describe it as a oozing light, but an oozing light is too non-specific.

Comment: Perhaps an [**aurora**](https://www.lexico.com/definition/aurora) or **beams** if generated by lamps pointing upwards, or a **glow** if it is created by general city lighting.

Comment: @stangdon I prefer to point out the error and let the poster correct it, so he or she learns something by doing so.

Comment: *Turquoise tongues of light (limning the liminal limestone...)* [The bill's in the post.]

Comment: The term “oozing light” is hard to understand. Ooze means to trickle out slowly, but light is the fastest thing in the universe. Can you explain what you mean?

Comment: @SegNerd OP means what the picture shows, and asked the question to improve on 'oozing'.

Comment: @WeatherVane is right. The picture depicts an aurora.

Answer (score 1):

I think it’s hard to describe this because it’s a computer generated image which doesn’t seem to really depict anything natural.

If I, as a native speaker, were asked to describe this to someone, I’d say it “looks sort of like a beam of light shooting upwards but also with a kind of glow around it.”

Thinking more about it, perhaps I could say the light was **emanating** from the top of the mountain, which might be good in this situation as it’s not particularly descriptive.

I could also describe it somewhat poetically as a kind of “fountain of light”.

I suppose it depends on your audience and what you’re trying to convey.